# Linux hosting with web-based shell access

Tags: ssh, shell, services, web, cloud

I am looking for a service that gives user some computing resources, a Linux OS and a preferably web browser based shell access.

Are there any services that you can recommend? The bandwidth usage will be minimal and mostly my batch experiments will be run on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find http://lowendbox.com/ useful - it's a blog site showing dirt cheap deals for virtual linux machines that you get full access to. You can often choose the flavour of Linux to use, and you get an ssh login.

Only thing is, you don't get browser based shell access (that I know of).

There are browser based ssh clients on the web - I just did a search and found this - http://www.serfish.com/console/; not sure I'd want to use something like that though. I'd stick with Putty or ssh on my own machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't specifically know of any ISPs that support this, but you might look for one that supports [noVNC](http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/), which would give you *console* access (which could be a shell, or could be a full X environment).  Having used this technology via [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/), I can say that it's a pretty useful way to get access to a machine, including (if you want it), GUI access, via your web browser.  Maybe you could find an ISP that has support for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get a cheap VPS that allows you to install your favourite Linux distro, have root access, you can then install and secure your own web base ssh?

Something like http://www.chicagovps.net/ they some low end plan.
Then you can install shellinabox which is basically an browser based shell access to your server, ssl secured.
You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/) to install it. 
Please make sure to allow non-root user only, and secure it with a strong password.